# switching between developer profile to distribution profile

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I'm creating an app with xcode 8 and up untill now all was good. But today I've encountered 2 problems :

1. Up untill now I was using development certificates for push service, today I added the production certificates and I don't get push notification no more.
   I'm using the AWS SNS service, and when I switch back to the development certificates, and send the push, I receive it with the connected device.
   Why is that? Why with the sandbox everything was ok, and now with the APNS it's not working though SNS says that the message was delivered successfully.
2. I've created a distribution profile and downloaded it and changed the xcode current profile. But now, the app won't compile on the device. On the simulator it works but on the device it says : process launch failed: failed to get the task for process 4383.
   Is it impossible to launch app on my device via xcode with AdHoc/Production profile / certificate?

The problem with the Push Notifications, I think, is that the device is generating tokens for sand box and not for production and therefore the push from APNS not working.

Is there a way to run app on device via xcode 8 with AdHoc/Production profile?

I'm at the final stage of the app, before distribution and I got stuck with these two problem which I think are connected.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: For question 2nd, it is impossible to install an app using production/distribution certificates via Xcode. And you can only test its functionality in it using test flight app. For this you need to upload the app on ITC using this distribution profile and then keep it on internal testing.

Answer (score 0):

APN SendBox is used when you install the app with Xcode.
If you ant to test APN you have to use a Distibution Ad Hoc Profile. Archivie the app, export as ad hoc and finally install the generated ipa using xcode.
In this way your app will use APN (Production)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate more on how you do it?